# Search nodes by AWS regions in Chef recipes

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I currently do something like `nodes = search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND recipes:recipe_name)` to get all the nodes with the same chef environment and recipe name. However, I have a couple single region clusters that use the same chef environment and recipe name, I was wondering if there is a way to add to the search query something like a `region` key, to only get nodes that are in the same AWS region.

Comment: Check the "placement_availability_zone" under the ec2 attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately and bizarrely the answer is no. The semi official solution from Amazon is to take the AZ name and trim off the last letter but that doesn’t help with search. You could make your own custom Ohai plugin to do that though. No one seems to be sure why Amazon doesn’t offer the plain region name via the metadata service.

EDIT: A more specific example

```
search(:node, "ec2_placement_availability_zone:#{node['ec2']['placement']['availability_zone'][0..-2]}*")
```

Comment: ah I see, I am not very familiar with Ohai, do you mind pointing me to some examples please?

Comment: Added a concrete example

Comment: In this case, is `ec2_placement_availability_zone` something I need to define?

Comment: No, that all comes from Ohai.